# PHP / MYSQL Insert on duplicate key update if CURDATE() match otherwise make new entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem in making a program with mysql and php...
See i want to save my search queries into the database,,
See this example

Stackoverflow searched = > 20 times on date = > 2013-04-26

Stackoverflow searched = > 10 times on date = > 2013-04-27

Stackoverflow searched = > 50 times on date = > 2013-04-28

Formatting does not matter..Actually i want to save my search queries if the date is changed..
If date got matched so should update times + 1

See this code,,

```
<?php

$keyword = null;
$date = null;

if (!empty($_GET['s'])) {


$keyword = stripslashes($_GET['s']);

$date = date("Y-m-d");

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:dbname=search;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');

            $check = "SELECT *
            FROM `search1`
            WHERE `keyword` = '$keyword%'
            AND `date` = CURDATE() ";

            if (!empty($check))
            {
            $sql ="UPDATE `search1`
            SET `times` = `times` + 1
            WHERE `keyword` = '$keyword%'
            AND `date` = CURDATE()";
            }
            else 
            {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `search1` (`keyword`, `date`) VALUES (:keyword, :date)";
            $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array(':keyword' => $keyword, ':date' => $date));

            }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


}
?>
```

It is not working.. Something is wrong.. Someone can tell me what is wrong.
I can not use primary key.

Comment: What error do you get? From what I see `UPDATE` part never goes to database . Also, you need to either compare `keyword` with `LIKE ` or get rid of "%" if you need to compare using equality operator.

Comment: Actually it does not save data in the database if i try to use  @a1ex07 WHERE `keyword` = '$keyword%' line in the code if i use a normal value  WHERE `keyword` = 'India' so it just find keyword india in the database and just update times value with + 1.. One more thing after adding this code  if (!empty($check)) this program is not saving new entries in the database...

Comment: `WHERE keyword = 'India%'` is looking for string "India%". `WHERE keyword LIKE 'India%'` is looking for string that starts with "India"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a unique index on the field date and keyword

```
ALTER TABLE  `search1` ADD UNIQUE (
`keyword` ,
`date`
);
```

edit: looks like the OP has got it now, but just for completeness, the above query you just run once to add a unique index to the table - note that it won't work if you have rows that have the same values for keyword and date; if you get a 'duplicate value' error you will have to remove rows until the values are unique before trying again.

then the query

```
INSERT INTO `search1` (`keyword`, `date`, `times`) VALUES (:keyword, :date, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `times` = `times` + 1
```

should do the trick :)

Comment: Hi where to place this code ALTER TABLE  `search1` ADD UNIQUE (
`keyword` ,
`date`
); will you please show me a demonstration with me code...

Comment: glad you got it sorted, sorry I wasn't about. added more detail anyways, happy coding :)